# Events listeners on elements contained with an object

Tags: javascript, html

I am building an e-commerce site and taking an OOP approach. I've run into a dilemma and I'm not too sure what I can do to fix this issue..

So I have class that is responsible to rendering the view of a shopping cart, let's call this `CartView`, which also has features that allows you to add and remove an item from that cart with event listeners attached to the add/remove buttons. Each time you add or remove, the cart gets re-rendered and a new shopping cart is created. However, at the same time, the event listeners get added to it again. So each time, the cart gets re-rendered another event listener gets added in an increasing fashion. So by the 5th re-rendering of the cart, there are 5 events that gets fired per click.

Example of what my code looks like:
**Store.js**

```
Store.prototype.onUpdate = function(itemName) {
    console.log('onUpdate');
    console.log(this);
    if (itemName) {
        var cart = document.getElementById("modal-content");
        var itemId = "product-" + itemName;
        var container = document.getElementById("productView");
        /*
            Below program crashes if our productView does not contain the item, we need
            a seperate communication with the server.
        */
        if (!document.getElementById(itemId)) {
            console.log(itemId + " does not exist in productView");
        } else {
            var currentItem = new ProductView(document.getElementById(itemId), this, itemName); 
            if (!nodeTraversal.findNode(container, document.getElementById(itemId))) {
                console.log('element does not exist');
                container.appendChild(currentItem);             
            } else {
                console.log('element does exist');
                var nodeToBeReplaced = document.getElementById("product-" + itemName);
                nodeTraversal.findReplacedNode(container, document.getElementById(itemId), nodeToBeReplaced);
            }           
        }

        console.log('cart', cart.childNodes);
        var cartView = new CartView(cart, this);
        cartView.initEvents(cart, this);
    } else {
        var stock = Object.keys(this.stock)
        var productsList = new ProductsView(document.getElementById("productView"), stock, this);
    }       
};
```

**CartView.js**

```
CartView.prototype.registerAddClickEventListeners = function(parent, storeInstance) {
    console.log(parent);
    console.log(parent.getAttribute('cartAddEvent'));
    if (parent.getAttribute('cartAddEvent') !== 'true') {
        console.log('Adding event for cart modal - add');
        parent.addEventListener("click", addClickEventListener(storeInstance), {once : true});
    }
}

function addClickEventListener(storeInstance) {
    return function(e) {
        if (e.target !== e.currentTarget && e.target.classList.contains("btn-add")) {
            var product = e.target.parentNode.classList.item(0);
            var elementClicked = e.target;
            elementClicked.setAttribute('cartAddEvent', 'true');
            storeInstance.addItemToCart(product);
            storeInstance.timer.resetTimer();
        }
        e.stopPropagation();        
    }
}
```

How can I make it such that the events get added only once? Ideally I would want feedback using pure javascript. Thanks!

Comment: To much code, please go to the essential part

Comment: @LéoMartin With all due respect, I put in the necessary code to provide context to my question